# Why is element not printed on some pages?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a basic element which contains a static text and text field in a band.  I have set 8 pieces of them after each other like rows of a table in a band and put them on one detail. The problem is that on the first page all elements are get filled and printed correctly. On the second page the 2 last elements wont printed. On the last page the last element wont be printed! I have no idea why it faces such a problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="direktRechrDV" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d12b4217-cf22-4ec4-857b-9cb1b2b406a8">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
<group name="id" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" keepTogether="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Id}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band/>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band splitType="Immediate">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="LBgroup" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" keepTogether="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{LB_ID}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band/>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band splitType="Immediate"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="62" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="8" y="2" width="409" height="26" uuid="37a242c0-b352-42e1-b287-42350a5e2090"/>
            <textElement markup="html"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Statistische Basisprüfung - Auffälligkeitskriterien: Verstetigung und Vollzähligkeit 2015<br>]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="7" y="16" width="322" height="19" uuid="f28c3fc0-6d00-4437-a185-febccf94e91f"/>
            <textElement markup="none"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idLb} +" - "+ $F{LB_LangBezeichnung}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="32" width="321" height="20" uuid="705007c1-4bfa-483a-a113-887cf7fd6488"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Id}+": "+$F{KN_BezeichnungAlleinstehendKurz}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <image hAlign="Center">
            <reportElement x="480" y="6" width="50" height="50" uuid="3f5fe998-e94e-4280-af71-7f7163878156">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{IMG_ID} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{Image}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="345">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{id_COUNT}.intValue()==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="8" y="40" width="501" height="270" uuid="55ca2869-dd02-48a5-a9bf-90b538ea22a6"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="280" height="21" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="255952d3-ed97-4615-926f-e7e89560d64a"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement key="" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="21" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="83851dcf-a0b2-44df-9117-0c5487b16260">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="AK.id"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.repeat.value" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="99" height="21" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="168d731e-09c0-4b1e-ac6f-c86168fe1286">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[AK_ID]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="21" width="280" height="21" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="0879346c-a263-431d-8e2d-8d2a1cd0e67c"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="99" height="21" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="75c8f9aa-47d6-4869-b8b2-a16ca58e11db"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Präfix]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement key="" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="21" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="f38998f8-8dc7-4ccc-8066-0cfe5e7ab876">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="qi.praefix"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.repeat.value" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{QI_Praefix}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="42" width="280" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="92186cbd-4a98-4c6e-9b51-0dfe52d5ff21"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="4818fc44-cde3-40ed-8d77-a6dd71b89f79">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="begruendung.relevanz"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.repeat.value" value="true"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement markup="html">
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Relevanz</b><br>" +($F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Relevanz} !=null ? $F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Relevanz} : "-")+"<br><b>Hypothese</b><br>" + ($F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Hypothese} !=null ? $F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Hypothese}: "-")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="99" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="a93eb1cf-015c-442a-afac-68c7f9a30cb5">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Begründung für die Auswahl]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="72" width="280" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="91d6b54a-bcd4-4737-8208-7dcd9e388ea4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="883db6cf-5cc6-4e32-a4cd-54bdf86b97df">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement rotation="None">
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Indikatorbezug} !=null ? $F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Indikatorbezug} : "-")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="-1" width="99" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="61373b56-22c7-4097-8da1-ebcd702bc410">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Bezug zu anderen Indikatoren]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="99" width="280" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="be213a60-4cd9-4f4a-972b-edfbf7b408c9"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="261644b6-bbdb-4528-9f25-7fb23e98bf99">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bewertungsArtTypNameKurz}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="99" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="d338843f-2f88-4d1b-b355-e7757acacf8e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Bewertungsart]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="127" width="280" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="626fe004-8942-4655-8c64-4022728e65e9"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="3ea786ed-6ce2-4ce7-84af-b4b7d29cc3b7">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mindesanzahlZaeler}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="-1" width="99" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="284779f8-692b-45b1-a535-62f1a4ce124b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Mindestanzahl Zähler]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="154" width="280" height="27" uuid="f2f30758-914b-4990-b508-644cabb06f3f"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="0" width="181" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="77c50b2a-a9ec-4225-8361-4daa6dc9d97e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Vergleichbarkeit_Vorjahr}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="99" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="4f5650a6-9330-444b-bfec-0c1cd03d254f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Vergleichbarkeit mit Vorjahr]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="182" width="280" height="27" uuid="3a70786a-ab1b-4193-8087-bcf9f363116a"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="99" y="-1" width="181" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="0d48b38a-07e8-42e7-89e8-e0580651028e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="1"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mindesanzahlNenner}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="-1" width="99" height="27" printWhenGroupChanges="id" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#005051" uuid="fc8232c6-dfb5-482a-9fef-a9ac1f75861a">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Mindestanzahl Nenner]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </frame>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="" hyperlinkTarget="" bookmarkLevel="1">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="4" width="340" height="6" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="56a6e5f3-fd57-436e-8acb-8dbc1acbb220">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[1==0]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Id}+":"+$F{nameAlleinstehend}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Id}+":"+$F{nameAlleinstehend}]]></anchorNameExpression>
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA[]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="11" y="14" width="78" height="16" uuid="17d269d4-d7fa-44ef-8b00-d1abe0ecb92c"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Berechnung]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="410" height="20" uuid="0744ba3c-69d3-4220-b201-72dabdeb5038"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ins]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField evaluationTime="Master">
            <reportElement x="481" y="18" width="69" height="24" uuid="5789c6a7-2ca2-4ba9-bd13-1b56ddcb7091"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Seite "+$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+" von"+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="52" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I'm guessing some since I have not same data as you (I can only see your jrxml). Let me know, if its a good guess,

Comment: I rollbacked your question to previous version since the images would only confuse future readers (hence they where after solution), thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have same data in previous record and this attribute on reportElement

```
isPrintRepeatedValues="false"
```

tells jasper **to not** print if field value is the same as on previous record.

**Set**

```
isPrintRepeatedValues="true"
```

> **isPrintRepeatedValues**, sets whether or not repeating values (same
>   values, equals) should be printed or not, its mostly used (set to
>   false) in table layout where you do not like to see same value again
>   in the following rows, you like only to display it when it changes.

Comment: I did as you said but nothing changed

Comment: @Iman You are missing values, correct?, they are not moving to next page?, can you show a screen shot of the output... (you are sure you do not have null in field values)

Comment: I am missing the hole element. static text and value, and I am sure the there should be value in field. I have checked it in data base

Comment: @Iman I can't understand your images I see 8 rows in each image, what are you missing in the images?

Comment: You are right! But it was not like this before. I did not notice that they are correct after last changes. Sorry about that. I isPrintRepeatedValues="true" and removed start new page fromLBGroup